# Loop data and display in html overlay

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I have a loop for displaying a name field, and a nested loop to display categories from each name  stored in database.

```
<?php if( get_field('servicos') ): ?>
                    <?php while( the_repeater_field('servicos') ): ?>
                        <?php while( the_repeater_field('servico') ): ?>
                            <h2 onclick="openNav()">
                                <?php the_sub_field('nome'); ?>
                            </h2>
                            <?php while( the_repeater_field('caegorias') ): ?>
                                <a href="#" class="color-white">
                                    <p><?php the_sub_field('categoria'); ?></p>
                                </a>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <div id="servicos-overlay" class="overlay-servicos">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                                <div class="overlay-content uppercase">
                                    <?php while( the_repeater_field('caegorias') ): ?>
                                        <a href="#" class="color-white">
                                            <?php the_sub_field('categoria'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif;?>
```

Each category must open in an overlay when the corresponding name is clicked.

When the name is clicked this javascript function is called and the overlay slides into the screen.

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("servicos-overlay").style.width = "100%";
}
```

The problem is when the overlay is displayed no matter what name was clicked the data in the overlay is always the first lap of the loop. The same category is displayed in all names, inspite of triggering the field for the last name.

If i change javascript function to loop `class="overlay-servicos"`i alway get the last row stored in the database for field category.

Does any one knows how can i open the overlay with the data corresponding to its name in the database?

Ps: if i remove overlay, and loop data in same div everything works ok.

Comment: All your `overlay-servicos` divs have the same `id`, so when you use `document.getElementById("servicos-overlay")` it always refers to the first one on the page. You need to use distinct `id` values for each div.

Comment: The div is always the same, will not be better to work with classes and loop through the class collection?

Comment: I have tried looping the className but didnt work either. Only outputs the last row of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML and PHP**

```
<?php if( get_field('servicos') ): ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while( the_repeater_field('servicos') ): ?>
        <?php while( the_repeater_field('servico') ): ?>
            <h2 onclick="openNav(<?php echo $count ?>)">
                <?php the_sub_field('nome'); ?>
            </h2>
            <?php while( the_repeater_field('caegorias') ): ?>
                <a href="#" class="color-white">
                    <p><?php the_sub_field('categoria'); ?></p>
                </a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div id="servicos-overlay-<?php echo $count ?>" class="overlay-servicos">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <div class="overlay-content uppercase">
                    <?php while( the_repeater_field('caegorias') ): ?>
                        <a href="#" class="color-white">
                            <?php the_sub_field('categoria'); ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $count++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var current_i = 0;
function openNav(i) {
    closeNav();
    document.getElementById("servicos-overlay-" + i).style.width = "100%";
    current_i = i;
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("servicos-overlay-" + current_i).style.width = "0%";
}
```

Comment: Console error -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at openNav (hello-clusters.js?ver=1:4)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick ((index):223)

Comment: I think is because i is not beeing passed to openNav(i) from the html div.

Comment: Yes it was the index of the loop in html not being passed. Problem SOLVED. Many thanks.